# Jmeter with Caching server

Tags: jmeter

My Application is using CDN which is a caching server. Now when I use JMETER for recording the functional flow. Browser doesn't load any CSS,JS or image being cached at CDN server. Removing CDN is alo not good option because I need to judge performance with CDN in place. Please Guide

Answer (score 0):

JMeter records only HTTP requests sent by browser, so if you have already visited this page your browser may already have these resources in its own cache therefore it doesn't send actual requests. If you want these requests to be recorded - you should clear your browsing history and especially delete cache. The procedure differs from browser to browser so check your browser documentation for details or check out [How do I clear my web browser's cache, cookies, and history?](https://kb.iu.edu/d/ahic) article.

In general you **should not** be recording these calls as real browsers download these images, scripts and styles using concurrent thread pool, i.e. one main request followed by parallel requests to get the resources. The same behavior can be set up in JMeter using "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler (or even better [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults), this way the setting will be applied to all HTTP Request samplers in scope)

[image: JMeter HTTP Request Default embedded resources]

Answer (score 0):

I accepted the Security certificate for CDN server through browser only. And problem was solved.